# I'm running into an error deploying heroku. I'm doing the latest rails tutorial through the cloud 9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org, cloud9-ide

here is the error message

```
2020-08-20T19:13:43.542139+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2020-08-20T19:13:43.603854+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-20T19:13:43.651479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-20T19:14:36.154142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-beach-80054.herokuapp.com request_id=30b35563-7447-4305-a243-8bce2664ee6a fwd="64.234.7.83" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-20T19:14:36.732461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-beach-80054.herokuapp.com request_id=59040236-bc19-4415-beb3-437f6c3dd7e1 fwd="64.234.7.83" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-20T19:17:01.054363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-beach-80054.herokuapp.com request_id=eee2212d-d741-46bb-81d7-3cdf6c4b5f76 fwd="64.234.7.83" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: OK, so what were you doing to generate the error?

Comment: @Brent B, Try to run the app in production mode locally and see if you face any issues & try to fix those